# Factorisation diagrams

Tags: graphics, number-theory, factorization

[Here](http://mathlesstraveled.com/2012/10/05/factorization-diagrams/) is a way to visualize the factorisation of natural numbers. How do we get this or a similar kind of output using *Mathematica*?

See the list of images generated for number from 1 to 36:

[image: factorisation diagrams for 1 to 36]

Comment: This reminds me of Richard Schwartz's book [You Can Count on Monsters](http://amzn.com/1568815786).

Answer (score 29):

Here is a recursive method using [Outer](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Outer.html):

```
FactorPoints[{1}] := {{0, 0}}

FactorPoints[{n_}] := 
 3/2 Csc[Pi/n] Through[{Cos, Sin}[# (2 Pi)/n]] & /@ Range[n]

FactorPoints[{n_, rest__}] := 
 Flatten[Outer[Plus, 9/4 Csc[Pi/n] FactorPoints[{rest}], 
   FactorPoints[{n}], 1], 1]

FactorPlot[n_] := 
 Graphics[Disk /@ 
   FactorPoints[Sort[Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ FactorInteger[n]]]]]
```

E.g. `FactorPlot[30]`:

[image: Factor plot of 30 == 5 * 3 * 2]

And `Grid[Partition[Table[Show[FactorPlot[n], ImageSize -> 60], {n, 36}], 6], Frame -> All]`:

[image: First attempt at replicating factor plot table]

Some manual tweaking will be required to get the same layout as in your example above. In particular, the special case `FactorPoints[{2, 2}]` should be implemented to get the nice square shape that has been chosen in your original example:

```
FactorPoints[{2, 2, rest___}] := FactorPoints[{4, rest}]
```

Then you get very close, except for some choices about orientation of each piece:

[image: Better attempt at factor plot table]

Comment: +1 for [`ConstantArray @@@`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5060681/618728) -- among other things. ;-)

Answer (score 24):

Let me introduce the following animated approach:
[image]

As you can see, I've slightly changed the way of diagram generation. The main differences are the following.

**1.** Now the diagrams are more symmetric. This is due to proper rotation after each sudivision.

**2.** As the main principle is to use factors in decreasing order, I consider 4 as a separate factor and place it before 3.

It is also should be noted that the total area of dots in each diagram is constant.

```
factorMovie[n_, fpm_, opts___] := 
  Module[{k, r0, r1, len, disksat, splitpts, pts, ns, prange, frames, 
    ptsat, line},
   line[t_] := t^2 (-1 + 2 t (7 + 2 t (-5 + 2 t)));
   disksat[t_] := Disk[# , r0 (1 - t) + r1 t] & @@@ ptsat[line@t];
   ptsat[t_] := {#1 + t len {Sin@#2, Cos@#2}, #2} & @@@ pts;

   splitpts[nn_] := Block[{},
     r0 = r1;
     r1 = r0/Sqrt[nn];
     pts = 
      Sequence @@ Table[{#1, #2 + (2 \[Pi])/nn i}, {i, 0, nn - 1}] & @@@
        ptsat[1];
     len *= Sin[\[Pi]/k]/(3 Sin[\[Pi]/nn]); k = nn;
     ];
   r0 = 1.5;
   len = 5;
   prange = 8;
   ns = Flatten[
      ReplaceRepeated[
       Table[#1, {#2}] & @@@ 
        FactorInteger[n], {a___, 2, 2, b___} :> {a, 4, b}]]~Sort~
     Greater;
   k = ns[[1]];
   r1 = r0/Sqrt[k];
   AppendTo[ns, ns[[-1]]];
   pts = Table[{{0, 0}, (2 \[Pi])/k i}, {i, 0, k - 1}] // N;
   frames = {};
   Do[
    frames = 
     frames~Join~
      Table[Graphics[disksat[t], PlotRange -> prange, opts], {t, 0, 1,
         1/fpm}];
    splitpts[m],
    {m, Rest@ns}
    ];
   frames
   ];

movies = Table[factorMovie[n, 10, ImageSize -> 80], {n, 2, 36}];
mlen = Max[Length /@ movies];
PrependTo[movies, Table[movies[[1, 1]], {mlen}]];
ms = If[(l = Length[#]) < mlen,
     Join[#, Table[#[[-1]], {mlen - l}]], #] & /@ movies;
frames = GraphicsGrid[Partition[#, 6], Frame -> All] & /@ 
   Transpose[ms];
ListAnimate[frames~Join~Reverse@frames, 
 AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward]
```

And finally one more factoring movie for 420:
[image]

```
n = 7 5 4 3
movie = factorMovie[n, 25, ImageSize -> 640];
frames = Join[Table[First@movie, {5}], movie, Table[Last@movie, {5}]];
ListAnimate[frames, 25, AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward]
```

---

**UPDATE**

I've modified the rules of diagram generation regarding Andrew's comment below. Now the factoring is mathematically strict in a sense that 4 is not considered prime like above.

[image]

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d9Ld.gif) is the animatied version.

I've also cleaned the code but still it needs some tweaking which I don't have time for.

```
factorMovie[n_, fpm_, opts___] := 
  Module[{k, r0, r1, len, disksat, splitpts, pts, ns, prange, frames, 
    ptsat, line, s},
   line[t_] := t^2 (-1 + 2 t (7 + 2 t (-5 + 2 t)));
   disksat[t_] := Disk[#, r0 (1 - t) + r1 t] & @@@ ptsat[line@t];
   ptsat[t_] := {#1 + t len {Sin@#2, Cos@#2}, #2} & @@@ pts;
   splitpts[nn_] := Block[{}, r0 = r1;
     r1 = r0/Sqrt[nn];
     pts = 
      Sequence @@ 
         Table[{#1, #2 + \[Pi] (1 + 2 i + nn)/nn }, {i, nn}] & @@@ 
       ptsat[1];
     len *= 
      If[k == nn == 2, (4/9)^(s = 1 - s), 
       Sin[\[Pi]/k]/(3 Sin[\[Pi]/nn])];
     k = nn;
     ];
   r0 = r1 = 1;

   prange = 7;
   ns = Flatten[Table[#1, {#2}] & @@@ FactorInteger[n]]~Sort~Greater;
   k = First@ns;
   {len, s} = If[k == 2, {8, 0}, {12, 1}];
   pts = {{{0, -len}, 0}};
   frames = {};
   Do[
    splitpts[m];
    frames = 
     frames~Join~
      Table[Graphics[disksat[t], PlotRange -> prange, opts], {t, 0, 1,
         1/fpm}]
    , {m, ns}];
   frames
   ];

movies = Table[factorMovie[n, 8, ImageSize -> 80], {n, 2, 36}];
mlen = Max[Length /@ movies];
PrependTo[movies, Table[movies[[1, 1]], {mlen}]];
ms = If[(l = Length[#]) < mlen, 
     Join[#, Table[#[[-1]], {mlen - l}]], #] & /@ movies;
frames = GraphicsGrid[Partition[#, 6], Frame -> All] & /@ 
   Transpose[ms];
ListAnimate[frames, AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward]
```

And finally [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3fiP.gif) is the modified version of factoring 420.

Comment: Oooo, shiny! +1

Comment: Makes me dizzy ... :(

Comment: Very nice!${}{}{}$

Comment: Excellent work. These are beautiful! I agree, a rotation is the proper solution to get diagram symmetry. Question: Do you really need the special case for n=4 when you have the rotation?

Comment: @Andrew, thank you, this is a good idea, though it will require to adjust spacing factor for n=2 to get nice pictures. I will update the answer soon.

Comment: Amazing! However, you have some spacing issues with lots of 11 and 13 factors that end up with overlapping rings.

Comment: Yep, this is the one of issues: need to adjust the rule for subsequent indentations...

Comment: Your final animation http://i.stack.imgur.com/5d9Ld.gif is mesmerizing!

Comment: You might enjoy seeing [this](http://www.datapointed.net/visualizations/math/factorization/animated-diagrams/), which is nearly as good as yours!

Answer (score 21):

Here's my modest attempt:

```
shiftMe[g_, 1] := g

shiftMe[g_, {2, tag_Integer?Positive}] := If[OddQ[tag],
  Translate[Scale[g, 1/2], #] & /@ {{0, 1}, {0, -1}}, 
  Translate[Scale[g, 1/2], #] & /@ {{1/2, 0}, {-1/2, 0}}]

shiftMe[g_, k_?PrimeQ] := Translate[Scale[g, 1/k], 
     Through[{Cos, Sin}[2 π #/k - π/(2 k)]]] & /@ Range[0, k - 1] /; k > 2

factorizationDiagram[n_Integer?Positive] := Graphics[Fold[shiftMe,
   {Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, 
   MapIndexed[If[#1 == 2, Prepend[#2, 2], #1] &, 
    Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ FactorInteger[n]]]]]

Map[factorizationDiagram, Partition[Range[36], 6], {2}] // GraphicsGrid
```

[image: factorization diagrams]

Answer (score 13):

Szabolcs found a page that does animated transitions between the diagrams in JavaScript [here](http://www.datapointed.net/visualizations/math/factorization/animated-diagrams/). Here's an iterative implementation of the diagrams and some basic animated transitions between them.

```
DynamicModule[{shapes, t, n, next, keyframes}, 
 shapes[i_] := 
  Thread@{Table[
     ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"]@Rescale[a, {1, i}], {a, i}], 
    Disk /@ First@
      Fold[Module[{pts = #[[1]], r = #[[2]], 
          n = #2}, {Join @@ 
           Table[# + n r Through@{Cos, Sin}[a 2 Pi/n + Pi/2] & /@ 
             RotationTransform[a 2 Pi/n + If[n == 2, Pi/2, 0]]@
              pts, {a, n}], n r}] &, {{{0., 0.}}, 1}, 
       Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ FactorInteger@i]};
 t = 1;
 n = 1;
 next[] := 
  keyframes = 
   Thread[{Prepend[#, #[[1]]], #2} & @@ (shapes /@ {n, n + 1})];
 next[];
 Dynamic[If[(t += .02) >= n + 1, n++; next[]];
  Graphics[{Blend[{#[[1]], #2[[1]]}, t - n], 
      Disk[#[[2, 1]] + (t - n) (#2[[2, 1]] - #[[2, 1]])]} & @@@ 
    keyframes, PlotRange -> t*{{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   ImageSize -> 300]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Again, great! And thanks for refreshing this Q&A, I've not seen it yet.

Comment: Thanks! I'll update it with halirutan's PlotRange improvement.

Comment: Damn, that's pretty cool. +1

Answer (score 9):

This is Andrew's method with a few tweaks of my own.  The addition of the adjustment argument should make other customization a bit easier.

```
f[{1}] = {{0, 0}};

f[{2}] = {{0, -9}, {0, 9}}/8;

f[{2, 2, rest___}] := f[{4, rest}, RotationMatrix[π/4]]

f[{n_}, adj___] := 
  Array[3/2 Csc[π/n] {Cos@#, Sin@#} &[# 2 π/n + π/2] &, n].adj

f[{n_, rest__}, adj___] := 
  Tuples@{9/4 Csc[π/n] f[{rest}], f[{n}].adj} ~Total~ {2}

FactorPlot[n_, opts___] := 
  Graphics[Disk /@ f[Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ FactorInteger @ n], opts]

Grid[Array[FactorPlot[#, ImageSize -> {90}] &, 36] ~Partition~ 6, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]