# Animating transition between all graph representations obtained from curated data

Tags: graphs-and-networks, animation, curated-data

Pappus graph is one of many graphs whose various data is contained within Mathematica. Mathematica typically keeps several ways of representing such graphs:

```
GraphData["PappusGraph", "AllImages"]
```

will give its several representations:

[image]

I found these images pretty amazing - they look very different!

*How to create an animation that will gradually go through all representations of Papus graph?*

For example, to clarify the question, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/393520/78592) is an animation made by [Mark McClure](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/36/mark-mcclure) created by transitioning from one to another "hardcoded" plot of the same graph:

[image]

```
vc1 = # - {1, 1} & /@ {{0, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {1, 1}, 
  {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}};
vc2 = {{1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}, {-1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}, {-1, 0}, 
  {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}, {-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}};
vc[t_] := t*vc2 + (1 - t) vc1;
Animate[
  Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
    UndirectedEdge@@@{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 7}, {7, 6}, {6, 5}, {5, 1}, 
     {1, 6}, {4, 5}, {4, 7}},
    PlotRange -> 1.1, VertexCoordinates -> vc[t]],
  {t, 0, 1}, AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward]
```

How to do it for any graph that is available in Mathematica currated data, for representatios given by `GraphData[<graph name>, "AllImages"]`?

---

EDIT: *(after reading answers)* This is part of the animation obtained with DyckGraph, using belisarius' solution:

[image]

Also, BrouwerHaemersGraph:

[image]

Comment: For the record, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/393520/78592) is the original answer from Mark McClure. I believe that it's great to give him credits.

Comment: related: [46671](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46671/5478)

Comment: I suggest [a more sophisticated interpolation strategy](http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671): http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk1WF.gif If there is interest I can try wrapping it up in a function for use in belisarius's answer.

Comment: Yes, @Kuba, thanks for the link, it is truly related, and the aesthetics of those animations seem even more profound.

Comment: @Rahul Narain There is interest. Thanks for the idea/aproach anyway.

Comment: I also have an idea of applying different interpolation strategy, called "progressive disclosure", on top of belisarius' solution. If results are fine, I am going to publish here an answer tomorrow, or maybe later.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The following is a little involved, but it calculates the "minimum displacement" evolution by choosing the least total displacement alternatives from the permutations generated by the *"AutomorphismGroup"*  of the graph:

```
{n, edges, coords1, perms} = GraphData["PappusGraph", {"VertexCount", "EdgeList", 
                                       "AllVertexCoordinates", "AutomorphismGroup"}];
coords = Transpose[Rescale /@ Transpose@#] & /@ coords1;
validPerms = GroupElements@perms;
calcPerm[1] = 1;
calcPerm[i_] := First@Ordering[ Tr /@ (EuclideanDistance @@@ Transpose@{perm[i - 1], #} & /@
                                      (Permute[coords[[i]], #] & /@ validPerms))]
perm[i_] := perm[i] = Permute[coords[[i]], validPerms[[calcPerm@i]]]
f[x_] := Sin[FractionalPart@x Pi/2]^2
Animate[
 j = Min[IntegerPart@i, Length@coords - 1];
 Graph[edges,  VertexCoordinates -> Thread[Range@n -> f@t perm[j + 1] + (1 - f@t) perm[j]], 
       PlotRange -> {{-.2, 1.2}, {-0.2, 1.2}}],
 {t, 1, Length@coords, .005},
 {i, 1, Length@coords, .005},
 DisplayAllSteps -> True, AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward]
```

[image]

The following (and more elegant) code for performing the same was done by shamelessly stealing some parts from @Vitaliy's code (from the [notebook](http://www.wolfram.com/training/special-event/wolfram-visualization-virtual-workshop-2013/MasteringDynamicVisualizationsWithMathematica.zip) he linked in [his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48656/193))for using `BSplineFunction[]` as the evolution path instead of my previous linear interpolation.

```
{n, adj, coords1, perms} = GraphData["PappusGraph", {"VertexCount", "AdjacencyMatrix", 
                                   "AllVertexCoordinates", "AutomorphismGroup"}];
coords = Transpose[Rescale /@ Transpose@#] & /@ coords1;
validPerms = GroupElements@perms;
calcPerm[1] = 1;
calcPerm[i_] := First@Ordering[Tr /@ (EuclideanDistance @@@ Transpose@{perm[i - 1], #} & /@
                              (Permute[coords[[i]], #] & /@ validPerms))]
perm[i_] := perm[i] = Permute[coords[[i]], validPerms[[calcPerm@i]]]
Manipulate[
 AdjacencyGraph[adj, VertexCoordinates -> (#[t] & /@ (BSplineFunction[#, SplineDegree -> 1, 
                    SplineClosed -> True] & /@ Transpose[perm /@ Range@Length@coords])),
  PlotRange -> {{-.2, 1.2}, {-0.2, 1.2}}],
 {t, 0, 1, Animator, AnimationRunning -> False, AnimationRate -> .02, ImageSize -> Small}]
```

**Previous (simpler)  Answer using the default paths instead of the minimal one. Run it to see the difference**

```
edges = GraphData["PappusGraph", "EdgeList"];
coords1 = GraphData["PappusGraph", "AllVertexCoordinates"];
coords = Transpose[Rescale /@ Transpose@#] & /@ coords1;
f[x_] := Sin[FractionalPart@x Pi/2]^2
Animate[
 j = Min[IntegerPart@i, Length@coords - 1];
 Graph[edges, VertexCoordinates -> Thread[Rule[Range@Length@First@coords, 
                                          f@t coords[[j + 1]] + (1 - f@t) coords[[j]]]], 
       PlotRange -> {{-.2, 1.2}, {-0.2, 1.2}}],
{t, 0, Length@coords - 1, .005},
{i, 1, Length@coords, .005},
DisplayAllSteps -> True, 
AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward]
```

Comment: Bravo! Standing ovation. +1

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks! You may want to sit down now. :)

Comment: Congratulations for surpassing 50k! And you passed it in a superior way, with this beautiful answer!

Comment: @VividD Thanks. Glad you like it :)

Comment: Amazing. ${}{}$

Comment: @RahulNarain Thanks! I'm really very pleased with the aesthetics of the resulting animation. And I never thought it was (kind of) easy to get the "minimal displacement problem" solved. It's the main reason why I like Mma: it lets me solve problems that could take me a month in less than a day.

Comment: @RahulNarain what happened to your answer? I think it is important to address interpolation issue... Bring your answer back! I also plan to propose a related improvement...

Comment: @belisarius Great, great, great!

Answer (score 14):

Have you seen my course:

[Mastering Dynamic Visualizations with Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?channel=317&video=1330)

- [**notebook**](http://www.wolfram.com/training/special-event/wolfram-visualization-virtual-workshop-2013/MasteringDynamicVisualizationsWithMathematica.zip) can be found [**HERE**](http://www.wolfram.com/training/special-event/wolfram-visualization-virtual-workshop-2013/) - look at the slide 5 and in the video about at 10 minutes from start.

I did something similar there but with ability to browse the data and adjust graph layouts manually and bookmark them and animate through it.

[image]

[image]

Simple 1st image code is below. Code for 2nd image please find in linked notebook - it has in-code images - hard to paste here.

```
Manipulate[

 AdjacencyGraph[amvcgd[[k, 1]],
  VertexCoordinates -> (#[
       t] & /@ (BSplineFunction[#, SplineDegree -> 1, 
         SplineClosed -> True] & /@ 
       Transpose[
        Transpose /@ 
         Map[Rescale, Transpose /@ N[amvcgd[[k, 2]]], {2}]])),
  ImageSize -> {400, 400}, GraphStyle -> gs]

 , {t, 0, 1, Animator, AnimationRunning -> False, 
  AnimationRate -> .02, ImageSize -> Small},
 {gs, {"BackgroundBlack", "ThickEdge", "BasicBlack", "Prototype", 
   "SimpleLink", "LargeNetwork", "SmallNetwork"}},
 {{k, 7, ""}, lofofr},

 Initialization :> (logn = {"PappusGraph", "DodecahedralGraph", 
     "CoxeterGraph", "Foster048A", "TesseractGraph", 
     "IcosahedralGraph", "LeviGraph", "TruncatedDodecahedralGraph", 
     "Balaban10Cage", "Foster056A", "TruncatedIcosahedralGraph", 
     "DeltoidalHexecontahedralGraph", 
     "SmallRhombicosidodecahedralGraph"}; 
   amvcgd = 
    GraphData[#, {"AdjacencyMatrix", "AllVertexCoordinates"}] & /@ 
     logn; lofofr = MapThread[Rule, {Range[13], logn}]),

 SynchronousUpdating -> False, FrameMargins -> 0]
```

Comment: I hadn't seen your course, and now that I saw it... it is amazing! I like your focus on big picture, as opposed to technical details!

Comment: @VividD Vitaly's fondness for "the big picture" comes with age. It's proper name is _Hyperopia_

Comment: @belisarius this time you really cracked me up... and i thought it's the children for whom the trees are taller.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov :) Very nice pictures here, indeed!

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Stole some code from your notebook. Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: @belisarius perfectly fine ;)